# Setter methods for final fields

Tags: java

Using reflection and also from the src.zip available in the installed JDK by the installer  purveyed by http://docs.oracle.com, I found the following fields of `java.lang.System`,

**in**,  **out** & **err** are declared as final, but they have respective (public) setter methods which in turn invoke their respective native couter-part.

For example, I could successfully re-direct console output to a file.

We can set final variables exactly once we have initialized it in the Java code.

My question is : is this rule of final not applicable to the native code?

Comment: To set these values Java uses native methods like `private static native void setOut0(PrintStream out)`. In pure Java you cant do it.

Comment: So with JNI, final fields are thread-safe?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> My question is : is this rule of final not applicable to the native code?

Native code can break the rules on `final`.  It can also break the access rules and basic type safety, and various other things.

The point about `final` fields not actually being immutable is actually recognized in the JLS: see [JLS 17.5.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5.3).  The gist of this is that if you do change a `final` (via reflection for example), certain guarantees no longer hold.  And changing the value of a `final` that represents a compile time constant is liable to have no effect at all.

But as @ignis points out, `System.in/out/err` get special mention in the JLS as being "write-protected" ([JLS 17.5.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5.4)) rather than having the normal `final` semantics.  Basically, this means that the `final` guarantees **do** hold even if the variables are changed.

---

> why have the variables to be final when there will be a setter anyways?

In this particular case it is 1) to prevent `System.in/out/err` from being clobbered by an accidental assignment, and 2) so that changes can be controlled by the `SecurityManager`.

Comment: just out of interest: is there a reason for that? why have the variables to be final when there will be a setter anyways?

Answer (score 2):

`final` makes Java Compiler ensure that no code tries to change the field except initialization. In java.lang.System it is different

`public static void setOut(PrintStream out) {
        checkIO();
        setOut0(out);
}`

`private static native void setOut0(PrintStream out);`

From the point of view of javac there is no violation.

Comment: using reflection(like java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Object, Object) etc.) we can not modify the value of a final field, either?

Comment: even with the reflection we can't modify directly, but we can by changing that final modifier first using reflection...aah reflection is so powerful if permissions are granted

Comment: @vishal_aim Test it now, since Java 6 you cant

Comment: am using java 6 and it is working fine. any link where it is mentioned?

Comment: I actually mean field.setAccessible(true) does not help since Java 6

Comment: @EvgeniyDorofeev, AccessibleObject.setAccessible(boolean) is for relaxing accessibility modifier private,protected or default, etc., right?

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee not only, in can be used on final too

Answer (score 1):

in the source code, they are not reassigning for example `out` variable in the `setOut()` method

```
public static void setOut(PrintStream out) {
 checkIO();
 setOut0(out);
}
```

they send the passed stream to native code, and that code is responsible to set that stream for current use. So final variable is not being re-set and this variable is not used in native code, whatever stream it passes to native code , it uses that